# Using .indexOn with nested keys in Firebase

Tags: json, firebase

I have a a bunch of keys that i want to index using `.indexOn`

Suppose my data looks like the following.  I want to be able to use `.orderByChild("height")`.

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "stats": {
      "height" : 2.1,
      "length" : 12.5,
      "weight": 5000
    }
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "stats": {
      "height" : 4,
      "length" : 9,
      "weight" : 2500
    }
  }
}
```

How wound I specify the rule for indexing `height` which is a child of `stats`?  Do I have to restructure or flatten my data?

Comment: As far as I know, this deeper-level (or multi-value) indexing is not (yet) possible. We touched on something similar here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910242/querying-nested-data-in-firebase/26911429#26911429) and I haven't seen any response from a Firebaser saying that it **is** possible; not have I been able to get non-trivial (i.e. multi-value.) keys working. So for the moment it looks like you will have to create your own index for these, as documented in the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 30):

You can query and index arbitrarily deep now.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$dinosaur": {
      ".indexOn": ["stats/height"]
    }   
  }
}
```

and query on nested values:

```
.orderByChild('stats/height')
```

Comment: I am getting error . Uncaught Error: Query.orderByValue failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects none.(…)

Comment: @akshay try 
    .orderByChild('stats/height')

Answer (score 18):

**Update 2015/12/17:** Firebase now supports deep indexing, so see Tom's answer.

---

You can arbitrarily nest indexing rules in your data tree, though you can only query the attributes of one list of elements at a time - not arbitrary deep. Here's some example rules, to index height:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$dinosaur": {
      "stats": {
        ".indexOn": ["height"]
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: So how would I query this? I tried setting up the query with something like the following but nothing get's returned.  Thanks for your help.    
`var fb = new Firebase("https://a_fb_ur./dinosaur");`  
`fbQuery = fb.orderByChild("height").equalTo(4);`

Comment: You'll have to flatten your data in order to do that query, and then you need to attach a listener to retrieve data. i.e. `new Firebase(...).child('dinosaurs').orderByChild('height').on('child_added', function(snapshot) { ... })`.

Comment: Okay; For storing [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples) I'll probably want to flatten the data then cause I'll commonly want to index and search on keys stored in the nested "properties" key.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: complete query is `new Firebase(...).child('dinosaurs').orderByChild('height').equalTo(4).on(...)`

Comment: anyway the Firebase doc doesn't give exemple of wildcard node applied on indexes, as it applied in security rules, it's logical it works for indexes too. Thanks to get the idea

Comment: This answer is out of data, Firebase now supports deep indexing (see my answer)