# Firebase Database retrieve with where

Tags: objective-c, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data from the Firebase Database using this:

```
[[[[_ref queryOrderedByChild:@"name"] queryStartingAtValue:@"Smith"] queryEndingAtValue:@"Smith\uf8ff"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
```

and the result is all records starting with "Smith" the name field.

But I want to get all records where the name field has in any position "Smith". So I have tried this:

```
queryStartingAtValue:@"%Smith%"
```

with only the queryStartingAtValue i get back the records that has in any position in the name field "Smith" and after that all other records, as I haven't put in the queryEndingAtValue.

When adding this:

```
queryEndingAtValue:@"%Smith\uf8ff%"
```

it is strange, because I don't get any record.

Does anyone has found a solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `%` signs are meant to do, but Firebase's query language is not the same as SQL's `WHERE` clause. Can you remove the `%` signs and try again?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: removing the % works perfect, but only retrieves records where the field name begins with "Smith", it is not retrieving records where the name has for example "John Smith".

Comment: Firebase doesn't offer that kind of query - you can't directly query for a sub-string within a string. However, there are alternatives posted here on stackoverfllow. Here's one with a different question but the answer is relevant [real time searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870425/swift-how-can-i-use-shouldchangetextinrange-with-firebase-for-real-time-sear/36872475#36872475) and [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search) and [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string)