# How to query nested objects in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a query string, so the response from **Firebase** only returns the rows with corresponding `userId` (*Not in top level*).
The goal is to only get the orders for the user who currently logged in.

My Javascript object is like this:

```js
const order = {
  itemId: "9T9WvJBbHiQpqyWdhBO0yX7lRny1"
  price: 5.3,
  customer: {
    userId: "-L9EyOPFB2PnyAPFUH9M",
    name: "demo user",
    address: "some place in earth",
  }
}
```

In Firebase, I have rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": ["userId"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is obviously not working out, since the index is pointing at top level.

Here is the URL I created for the API call:

```js
const queryParams = `?auth=${token}&orderBy="userId"&equalTo="${userId}"`;

axios
  .get('/orders.json' + queryParams)
  .then(res => {
    // get orders for the currently logged-in user
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

If I move `userId` one level up, this works completely fine, but customer and authenticated user are using same ID, so I rather keep them in one object.

Is it possible to query data with nested index in Firebase?
If so, what rules and query string should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to order on `orderBy="customer/userId"`.

You'll also need to define the index on that nested field, which is done like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": ["customer/userId"]
    }
  }
}
```

Just quickly confirmed that last one against [Tom's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341984).

Comment: Wow. It works. Is there a reference documentation for this? I tried to use `"$"` to connect them, since it's used in mongoDB : (